# Why doesn't ARRAY_PUT dedupe objects with null properies?

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

According to https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html:

> ARRAY_PUT(expression, value, ...)
>
> This function returns a new array with value(s) appended if the value
> is not already present. Otherwise, it returns the unmodified input
> array.

But I've found that if the value is an object with a null property, it never matches existing values in the array.

For example, take the following query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_PUT([{'foo': 0}], {'foo': 0})
```

The result is:

```
[{"foo": 0}]
```

Now change the properties to null:

```
SELECT ARRAY_PUT([{'foo': null}], {'foo': null})
```

The result is:

```
[{"foo": null}, {"foo": null}]
```

Why doesn't ARRAY_PUT dedupe objects with null properties?

Answer (score 0):

NULL means undefined and comparison of {"foo": null} = {"foo": null} will return NULL which is false (Unless it is Used as expression IS NULL). Due to that it will not dedupe values.